# Using Apply vs Manual to Operate on Pandas Columns

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, apply

Apologies if this has been asked before but I couldn't find this exact question answered. I want to take the values in 2 Pandas Data Frame columns, divide them, and store it in a new column in the df for all rows.

**My Question is:**
Is it more efficient/better practice to use the `apply` lambda function on a Pandas Data Frame in Python or to do the column operations "directly"? Or if there's another more accepted practice that would be appreciated as well.

"Directly":

```py
df["Ratio"] = df["x"] / df["y"]
```

Versus with `apply` lambda:

```py
df["Ratio"] = df.apply(lambda row: row.x / row.y, axis=1)
```

Comment: This is a really good question to ask for a beginner and the answers in the duplicate link explain it thoroughly. Good luck learning pandas

Comment: That was perfect, thank you! I had trouble finding a question like that.